# Create CSV file MAC

Tags: vba, macos, excel

My code keeps bugging at

```
        .SaveAs FileName:=Pth, FileFormat:=xlCSV
```

I'm working on a MAC, but its supposed to be working on both Mac and windows, Does anybody know how to fix this? :)

```
    Sub Opgave8()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim user_id As String
    Dim file_name As String
    Dim Pth As String
    Dim overwrite_question As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    user_id = Environ$("USERPROFILE")
    file_name = "AdminExport.csv"
   ' Pth = user_id & "\Desktop\" & file_name
   Pth = user_id & Application.PathSeparator & "Desktop" & Application.PathSeparator & file_name

    Set sh = Sheets.Add

    For i = 2 To 18288
        If Left(Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 12), 6) = "262015" Then
            sh.Cells(i, 2) = Worksheets("Base").Cells(i, 4)
        End If
    Next i

    sh.Move

    overwrite_question = vbNo
    If Dir(Pth) <> "" Then
        overwrite_question = MsgBox("File already exist, do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo)
    Else
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:=Pth, FileFormat:=xlCSV
            .Close
        End With
    End If

    If overwrite_question = vbYes Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs FileName:=Pth, FileFormat:=xlCSV
            .Close False
        End With
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub




Function UniqueRandDigits(x As Long) As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Do
        n = Int(Rnd() * 10)
        If InStr(s, n) = 0 Then
            s = s & n
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Loop Until i = x + 1

    UniqueRandDigits = s
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That path won't work on a Mac. You should use something like this:

```
Pth = user_id & Application.Pathseparator & "Desktop" & Application.Pathseparator & file_name
```

Comment: 'AdminExport.csv' cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only.

Debug in same line of code

Comment: That doesn't address my question. Is the **value** of `Pth` correct?

Comment: What do you mean with the value of Pth exactly?

Comment: Exactly that - what is the value stored in the variable `Pth`? May I suggest you go and read the late Chip Pearson's article on debugging here: http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx

Comment: The value is just the Path on the computer i guess? Cant you see in the code what the value is? :-)

Comment: No, we can't. *Please* go read that article. :) At the very least learn how to check the value of a variable - it will make your life a lot easier. You need to be able to check that the path stored in the variable actually exists. If it does, you may be running into Mac sandboxing.

Comment: What i could find out from the artice, is the value just set as "" in my document.

Comment: Add `Msgbox Pth` after the line that sets it and see if the value is correct.

Comment: It gives me this then:
/Desktop/AdminExport.csv

Comment: Which suggests that the `Environ$("USERPROFILE")` part is not working. You probably need MacScript to get the right folder - have a look at Ron de Bruin's site.

Comment: I'll do that. Thank you so much for your help, i actually learned something else besides what i asked for. Good day :)

Comment: You're welcome. Ron's site (http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm) is the best I know of for Excel VBA on the Mac.